# Youtube embedded video suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have an embeded youtube player on a website

Here is how it is set up.

- A Youtube embed iFrame is present in markup

```html
  <iframe 
      id="video_1"
      class="yt-video"
      data-modal-id="vid_modal_1"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Fh1a2K9ZgNA?enablejsapi=1&html5=1&origin=http://d.mydomain"
      allowfullscreen=""
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
      width="675"
      height="380"
      frameborder="0">
  </iframe>
```

- The Youtube iframe API is loaded in head
- On `window.onload` event, `YT` player is created using this code

```js
  // --- file2.js ---
  //
  // --- closure code unrelated to this feature ----
  // ...
  //
  window.isYouTubeIframeAPIReady = false;

  window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
      window.isYouTubeIframeAPIReady = true;
  };

  function onPlayerReady() {
      alert( 'player is ready' );
  }

  $(window).on('load', function () {
      //
      // some polling happens here and code only proceeds if
      // window.isYouTubeIframeAPIReady is true
      //
      if( window.isYouTubeIframeAPIReady == true ){
          var p = new YT.Player(id, {
              'events': {
                  'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                  'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
              }
          });
      }
  }

  // --- closure code unrelated to this feature ----
  // ...
  //
```

where `id` is id of the Youtube iFrame.

## The Problem

The `onReady` event callback only fires when the page is hard refreshed (`Ctrl+F5`). Normal refresh using browser refresh icon or hitting `F5` key doesn't fire the `onReady` event.

## Additional Info

The Youtube iframe API javascript file is loaded after `file2.js`.

## Update

Here is the screenshot of the javascript console displaying `p` (return of `new YT.Player(...)` when it works.
[image: p, when it works]
The object has many more methods... The screenshot is not complete

And here it is on the server where it does not
[image: p, when it doesn't]
Screenshots shows the complete object.

Comment: I have resolved it myself. Thanks for viewing the question.

Comment: would be nice if you actually say how you resolved it ...

Comment: @scibuff It was related to how the iframe was accessed inside the YT API's `onReady` event callback. Changing `var iframe = $(event.target.h);` to `var iframe = $(event.target.getIframe());` fixed it. Turned out that the iframe was not always stored in `h` property of `event.target` object hence the API had the proper method for accessing it which I somehow missed before.